# bottom right hand corner of cell is blue in excel

Tags: excel

does anyone know how to switch off the blue in the bottom right hand corner of a cell when there is a table linked to external data?

This is excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

For future readers

This dissapears when the sheets are protected